# Add SearchView to RecyclerView List

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, recyclerview-layout

I have a recyclerview populated with a list from an API. I am using RxBinding to search and filter the list. The current problem is with my layout. I would like my search bar field at the top with the list beneath it. Below is an example of my list being filtered but as you can see the searchbar text and the List Items overlap

[image: ListView]

Now below is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="text" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Eventually I want the searchbar to be scrollable as well, so that when the user scrolls down the list, the searchbar will be rotated out. However I think this will involve me created a list of some `CommonInterface` which my both my SearchBar and ListItems would have to implement.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout like this so that recyclerView is below the editText and add a scrollView so that the scrolling happens on the whole layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/edit"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="text" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And add this in your RecyclerView in Java:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I edited the answer, previously it was for listView not for recyclerView.

Comment: I’m not at my pc right now. But from looking at your proposed layout, It makes sense and I believe that will work. I will be able to test shortly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/atehensGray"

android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/chrome_grey"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```